# Can I control 2 Strymon pedals with a single favorite switch?

Tags: effects-pedal

I have 2 Strymon pedals, a Flint and a Dig. I just ordered a favorite switch. I would like to be able to recall favorite settings on each pedal. Can I control 2 Strymon pedals with a single favorite switch?

Comment: Have you asked the producer? There are things that can go wrong (like you can fry one strymon with another). On the other hand what you want is might be possible but may require knowing what you're doing, some work and expenses (e.g. replacing switch with dpdt which acts like 2 switches in one, and installing second jack socket)

Answer (score 1):

I presume you're referring to the Mini Switch (as opposed to the Tap Favorite, which has been discontinued). It has one TRS output that connects to the EXP jack of one pedal. There's no information about connecting it to multiple pedals, so I assume that doesn't work, or at least is not supported.

I own a MultiSwitch Plus, which has three TRS outputs. In Tap/Favorite/Boost/Speed Mode, you can control three pedals.

In theory you might be able to use a splitter and send the signal from your Mini Switch and to both the Flint and Dig at the same time, but I don't recommend trying it due to risk of damaging something.

Comment: Yes, I'm referring to the Mini Switch as opposed to the Tap Favorite.